# How does outer product work in R?

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra

As a part of trying to vectorize a loop I stumbled upon `outer(X, Y, FUN = "*", ...)` function in `R`.

I am trying to understand how to reproduce the following result step by step:

```
set.seed(1)
b = rnorm(3, 0, 1)
t = rnorm(5)
```

Using `outer()` with `FUN` argument as `-` I get the following output:

```
> outer(t, b, "-")
           [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
[1,] -0.9134962 -1.7235934 -0.70432143
[2,] -0.3021132 -1.1122104 -0.09293842
[3,]  0.3317334 -0.4783638  0.54090817
[4,]  0.6206866 -0.1894105  0.82986144
[5,]  3.0311072  2.2210101  3.24028200
```

Using `outer()` with `FUN` argument as `*` I get:

```
> outer(t, b, "*")
             [,1]         [,2]         [,3]
[1,]  0.964707572 -0.282801545  1.286826317
[2,]  0.581704357 -0.170525137  0.775937183
[3,]  0.184628747 -0.054123443  0.246276838
[4,]  0.003612867 -0.001059103  0.004819215
[5,] -1.506404279  0.441598542 -2.009397175
```

I am able to reproduce `outer(t, b, "*")` by doing `t %*% t(b)`, but I can't figure out how to do it for `outer(t, b, "-")`.

My knowledge of matrix algebra if fairly limited, but I want to give it a go. Can you, please, help me:

- reproduce the case where `FUN` is set to `-`
- shed some light on what `FUN` actually does?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question was migrated from `stats.stackexchange` and the original answer included mathematical equations. Below you can find the original text, as well as a picture in which the formatting is preserved.

**Image (formatting preserved)**

[image]

**Original text**

> The outer product of two vectors $x,y$ (which do **not** need to have
>   the same dimension) is often written $x y^T$ or, with more details, $$
>   \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \ x_2 \ \vdots \ x_n \end{pmatrix} \cdot
>   \begin{pmatrix} y_1 & y_2 & \dots & y_m \end{pmatrix} $$ and the
>   result is the $n \times m $ matrix $$ \begin{pmatrix}  x_1 y_1 & x_1
>   y_2 & \dots x_1 y_m \
>                    x_2 y_1 & x_2 y_2 & \dots x_2 y_m \
>                     \vdots  \
>                    x_n y_1 & x_n y_2 & \dots & x_n y_m \end{pmatrix} $$ So, you can see, the result is an $n\times m$ matrix where element
>   $i,j$ is given by $x_i \cdot y_j$.  So this is outer product where the
>   FUN is ordinary multiplication.  In general, the result is the same,
>   always an $n \times m$-matrix, where ordinary multiplication is
>   replaced with an arbitrary two-place function $\text{FUN}(x,y)$, so if
>   that function is ordinary minus, $-$ then the $i,j$ element becomes
>   $x_i - y_j$, if FUN is power, $\text{FUN}(x,y) = x^y$ then the $i,j$
>   element becomes $x_i^{y_j}$, and so on.
>
> This could even be used with non-numerical functions.

Comment: Great answer! To make sure I understand: so, `R`'s `outer()` *rearranges*   the vectors (transposes `y`) as if the product would be computed, but it actually does what the `FUN` argument specifies. Is this correct?

Comment: Thank you. Since the question was migrated, I made some edits to try improve the readability for other users.

Answer (score 2):

> I am adding an extra text answer because some day will expire that image and the Latex doesn't work here in StackOverflow.

This how outer multiplication works when performing it by hand:

```
# outer multiplication 
[1,2,3]*[4      1*4 , 1*5, 1*6  
         5  =   2*4 , 2*5, 2*6 
         6]     3*4 , 3*5, 3*6
# result:        
4,5,6
8,10,12      
12,15,18
```

And this how it work in R:

```
outer(1:3, 4:6)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    5    6
[2,]    8   10   12
[3,]   12   15   18
# same operation 
> 1:3 %o% 4:6
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    5    6
[2,]    8   10   12
[3,]   12   15   18
```

If we check the R documentation for the [`outer()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/outer) function:

> ```
> outer(X, Y, FUN = "*", …)
> X %o% Y
> ```
>
> **Arguments:**
>
> `X, Y` : First and second arguments for function `FUN`.
> Typically a vector or array.
>
> `FUN` : a function to use on the outer products, found via [`match.fun`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/link/match.fun?package=base&version=3.6.2) (except for the special case "*").
>
> `…` : optional arguments to be passed to `FUN`.
>
> **Details:**
>
> `X` and `Y` must be suitable arguments for `FUN`. Each will be extended by
> rep to length the products of the lengths of `X` and `Y` before `FUN` is
> called.
>
> `FUN` is called with these two extended vectors as arguments (plus any arguments in `…`). It must be a vectorized function (or the name of one) expecting at least two arguments and returning a value with the same length as the first (and the second).
>
> `FUN = "*"` is handled as a special case via `as.vector(X) %*% t(as.vector(Y))`, and is intended only for numeric vectors and arrays.